# Hide table column by id with JQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need to hide / show table columns with JQuery. Not so hard to find an answer : after a few researches, i found something that look like that :

```
$('#btnHide').click(function() {  
  $('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').toggle();  
});
```

Works quite well, but has one constraint : you have to give the column number.
In my case, things get taugher : the displayed columns depend on who you are (i.e. simple user : you juste get to see column 1, 3 and 5. Admid user : you see all columns)
This is set with php rules for more security. So I end up with my column "article" with the number "3" when admin, and "2" when user. The solution mentionned

=> I need a solution to use columns ids instead of column number. I've looked around a bit, but I couldn't find an answer. Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Where should the "id" values come from? The `<th>` header row?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the id to obtain the index of a particular column.

Something like

```
var $col_header = $("th#article"),
    col_index = $("#someTable th").index($col_header[0]);
```

Integrate that index with what you've already found.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I'm really sorry I took so long to get back to you : forgot to check the "notify me when new answers"... -_-'

Comment: Anyway. We had to find another solution (live project with limited time... ^^), but i'll keep your commentaries in mind.

Thanks a lot. =)

Comment: .indexOf() can not be used on a jQuery object.